# CreateFileA issue in windows XP and 7

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

When I create `hComm` value using `createFileA` function and doing the operation with USB device in Windows XP and 7 for the first time is working fine. But after restarting the USB device and calling `CreateFileA` function it returns `FILE_NOT_FOUND` error.But this doesn't happen in Windows 10. How could I solve this?

Comment: What parameters are you passing to `CreateFileA`? What do you mean by "restarting the usb device"? What _is_ the USB device? Note that Windows XP is end-of-life and Windows 7 is close to EOL, so the answer might simply be "meh".

Comment: Use Device Manager to see the COM port number that the device driver assigned.  It might have changed, too many crappy drivers around.  Do watch out for unplugging the device while your program is running, using the "Safely remove hardware" tray icon is a hard requirement for devices that don't support plug+play.

Comment: I am developing code for USB being integrated in our devices.After doing read or write operation from PC  we are restarting the USB device that is being written in the code.Following is the parameter i have been passing in the createFile A function.CreateFileA(com_port,                
                      GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 
                      0,                            
                      NULL,                      
                      OPEN_ALWAYS,
                      0,            
                      NULL);

Comment: In device manager i can see the PORT name after restarting my USB device.But createFileA function returns error

Comment: @Arun you did not show the actual value of the `com_port` variable. Also, `OPEN_ALWAYS` should be `OPEN_EXISTING` when opening hardware devices

Comment: @Remy  int open_serial_port(char *port_name,bool mssg_box_flag)
{
  DWORD dNoOFBytestoWrite;        
  DWORD dNoOfBytesWritten = 0;    
  wxString com_port = "\\\\.\\";
  if(hComm !=INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
  {
    CloseHandle(hComm);
  }
  printf("Starting... \n\r");
  com_port<<port_name;

  hComm = CreateFileA(com_port,        
                      GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 
                      0,
                      NULL,             
                      OPEN_ALWAYS,
                      0,            
                      NULL);

Comment: @Arun you still did not show the full value of `com_port`, what is `port_name` being set to? What value do you see in Device Manager and what value are you passing to `CreateFileA`? And you didn't change `OPEN_ALWAYS` to `OPEN_EXISTING`, per the documentation: "*For communications resources, **the dwCreationDisposition parameter must be OPEN_EXISTING**, the dwShareMode parameter must be zero (exclusive access), and the hTemplateFile parameter must be NULL.*"

Comment: Any Windows API for detecting  USB devices connection status?

Answer (score 0):

According to experience before, the Windows assign the `COM port` according `VID`, `PID` and `serial` number. So with the same device plug in, it should always get same `COM port` assignment.(I didn't test it on win7, XP)

Refer:[COM port assignement changes after reboot.](https://www.silabs.com/community/interface/forum.topic.html/com_port_assignement-uCuL)

One of the common errors while opening a `COM port` is that the `COM port` doesn't exist , you would get `ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`  as the last error.

So you can avoid USB/Serial adapter port change in Windows enviroment.

Refer: [Avoid USB/Serial adapter port change in Windows enviroment](https://superuser.com/questions/734172/avoid-usb-serial-adapter-port-change-in-windows-enviroment)

Comment: Any Windows API for detecting USB devices connection status?

Comment: @Arun `SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail` returns details about a device interface.

Comment: Any Windows API for detecting USB devices connection status from DEVICE MANAGER?

Comment: @Arun  All devices shown by Device Manager can be listed with the help of the `SetupDiGetClassDevs` function

Comment: @Arun If your question has been solved, please mark my answer.This can be beneficial to other community members reading this thread.  If not, please tell me where I need to solve it.